# Dynamically creatre response structure

Tags: java, spring

I want to dynamically create a specific response in my controller.

```
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getLanguageList() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new Object() ??
);
    }
```

And response on GET /test should be like that:

```
{
 status: "OK",
 info: "Hello"
}
```

How to do that? I don't want to create a new class for response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return a `Map<String, Object>` or `Map<String, String>` in the ResponseEntity. You can construct and add properties as you need in runtime to a map and it will be converted to a json structure by `ResponseEntity.ok. So, just do:

```
return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(map, HttpStatus.OK) ;
```